# spTransform error (unable to find inherited method for function spTransform)

Tags: r, sf

I am trying to reproject a shapefile.  For example, the land [shapefile](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/10m-land/) from Natural Earth.

```
library(sf)
shape <- read_sf(".../ne_10m_land.shp")

shape_proj<-spTransform(shape, CRS("+proj=gnom +lat_0=90 +lon_0=-50"))
```

I keep getting the following error, even when I try with CRSobj= or using other ways to express the CRS.

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :    unable to find an
>   inherited method for function ‘spTransform’ for signature ‘"sf",
>   "CRS"’

Comment: You're mixing two generations of vector features packages. `spTranform` is for sp objects (the 'old' way). For sf objects you must use `st_transform`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

check the data type,

```
class(shape)
```

if it returns sf "data.frame" you should use **st_transform** instead of **spTransform**

```
shape_proj<-st_transform(shape, CRS("+proj=gnom +lat_0=90 +lon_0=-50"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this function instead:
st_transform(shape,st_crs(shape2)) #that's if you want your CRS to match another coordinate system (shape2 in this case)